# Java SE vs Java EE, college and career

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm currently studying Computer Science at College where they mainly teach Java standard edition, I see that in the industry this isn't used much, instead Java EE is used. If my College is teaching me Java SE rather than Java EE does this make me less employable?

And what exact are the differences? different syntax? different way of programming or what?

Comment: See here: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106820/what-is-j2ee">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106820/what-is-j2ee</a>

Comment: Here's a hint -- drop the "I'm currently..." stuff.  The "...make me less employable?" isn't really a useful question -- it's a judgement call.  Focus on stuff we can answer: J2EE vs. J2SE and which people actually use.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Java 2 Enterprise Edition (J2EE) was renamed Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE; JEE) in 2005 or so. It'd be cool if people would finally adopt the current, simpler (and more logical) name...

Comment: @Jonik: Yeah, I'm getting sick of that, too. It's been three years. When I see "J2EE" I think Java 1.4

Comment: @Arjan Tijms : you have edited every answer including question. :)

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya haha, unfortunately there's no SO bonus for that :P

Answer (score 18):

For all intents and purposes, Java and Java SE are the same thing.  When you say you are learning Java SE, it means you are learning Java, its syntax, features and standard libraries.  You cannot learn Java EE before learning these skills.

Java EE is a set of standards which define many different interfaces and features for building software to address enterprise level problems.  These include things like transactions, distributed computing, messaging, web applications and resource management.  All of which are provided in a managed environment.  All of which is coded to the Java language, with particular rules and characteristics due to the environment in which the software will run.

Think of learning Java SE as learning to drive a car. Java EE is like learning to drive an 18 wheeler, you don't need to know how to do it to get from A to B, but it sure helps if you have to take 10 tons of cargo with you  8-)

Comment: I see it this way: "JSE" and "J2EE" are both "Java" if (a) you're a recruitment agency, or (b) you've been dealing with them for too long...

Answer (score 11):

Java SE contains the standard Java libraries: all the basics, containers, network, GUI, and so on. It's meant mostly for desktop apps and browser applets.

Java EE adds a server framework.  When you talk about Java in the server, this is what you're referring to.  It's a *huge* library, with lots and lots of pre-established 'best practices'.  Back when JITs were still young, the heavily scalable design of Java EE made it very well-received in the server, besides the (then significant) overhead of JVM.

I haven't really used Java EE in anything serious; but I think it's better to learn Java SE first, and then Java EE.  It takes more time; but lets you better understand what is the language and what is the framework.

Answer (score 8):

> If my  College is teaching me Java SE rather than
>   Java EE does this make me less
>   employable?

No. That's what your university should do: focus on fundamentals. In the case of Java, that mostly means the standard edition.

Java EE (*not* J2EE; see my comment in the question) adds some server-side Java APIs, specifications and libraries. The most important of these are the [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) API and [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) container specification. But I think it's important to know that even on the server side, it's still mostly about standard Java! It's quite possible that you'll do server-side Java development without ever needing to learn most Java EE technologies, like Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) - especially with the rise of alternative, lightweight approaches such as favouring [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POJO)s, with [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) for persistence layer. Many parts of Java EE like EJB have definitely long passed the peak of their hype cycle. You may not even need to know all "lower-level" Servlet and JSP stuff thoroughly, as higher-level frameworks such as [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/), [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/), or [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) have become popular.

One case study: I learned fundamentals of Java (and OO programming) at the university - and only *very* little (and nothing practical) about the Enterprise Edition. Now I've worked some 4-5 as "Java EE developer", that is, doing server side Java. I've never really used EJB, or most other Java EE technologies. I've mostly done just pure Java (i.e. standard edition), with some JSP, Servlets, Filters, etc related stuff thrown in (plus of course web techniques like HTML, JS, CSS); making use of *lots* of (mostly open-source) 3rd party libraries, and picking up everything as needed. (However, I am planning to brush up my knowledge of Java EE, and [take the SCWCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498889/is-the-scwcd-still-worthwhile-and-if-so-how-to-prepare) at some point - I think that would do me good even if Java SE goes a long way :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, university is really meant to teach you to be strong on the fundamentals and concepts not necessarily to teach you the exact skills you will need in a job.  So most of all I would recommend that you make sure you're learning the concepts found in enterprise application requirements (e.g. transactions, messaging queues/topics, etc...)  However, if this is really a concern for you I would suggest doing a self-study (possibly for course credit).  Also, try to find an internship that will let you play in some Java EE code.

I was asking myself the same question when I was nearing the end of university. I'm now working in a Java EE environment and there was some learning curve to use the Java EE libraries. I have to agree with many others and say that doing enterprise java development is not very much fun compared to other projects I've worked on so you might want to keep having fun in university and put off the boring stuff for when you're part of the workforce.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I view it.

The programming language as you know it is called Java.

Like most other programming languages, it also comes bundled with many standard libraries.

Java SE is the combination of both the language and certain libraries that makes general application development possible.

Java EE is another set of libraries that you can use in combination with Java SE to also develop enterprise/web applications.

Answer (score 1):

The Java language by itself is one aspect of Java development.  Applications built with the standard edition fulfill certain needs.  Thinking that you can just "wing it" with the enterprise edition if all you know is the standard edition, is a misconception.  The libraries make the language.  Although certain aspects of Java EE have their (deserved) critics, there is still a great deal of functionality there. Even the questionable parts are still used heavily in the industry.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition):

> The Java platform (Enterprise Edition) differs from the Java Standard Edition Platform (Java SE) in that it adds libraries which provide functionality to deploy fault-tolerant, distributed, multi-tier Java software, based largely on modular components running on an application server.

The syntax is the same. Everything you learn pertaining to Java SE will apply to Java EE. It simply adds a pile of new APIs, and calls for a certain style of application design that is well-suited to specific types of problems. Those kinds of problems (large, fault-tolerant, distributed, scalable, multi-tier...) and how to solve them are really what Java EE is about, not the actual APIs that happen to be part of the specification.

Remember that a CS degree isn't a vocational degree. It is meant to teach you how to learn and think, not train you in a specific skill-set tailored for a certain industry niche.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is just a superset of Java SE (enterprise libraries such as servlets). Learn Java SE and you mostly know Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the relation of Java SE (or "Core Java) and Java EE.

Core Java is important to learn and is what most schools will teach you.

Since programming revolves around using wheels rather than reinventing them, there are usually libraries with code for accomplishing complex tasks.

For examples, some schools teach people to build GUIs using the AWT or Swing class library that are supplied with Java, although there are other options.

Java EE, while supported by extra software to run the program on servers, can be thought of more as a library of classes and related services. You still do Java constantly, you just use a popular and Sun supported library. You will also see Hibernate and Spring that are not part of Java EE.

Most places will first of all want to make sure that your Java is solid. As you start working, you will gain experience at using specific parts of Java EE.