# Weblogic 11g and JavaEE 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, weblogic11g

I was wondering if Weblogic 11g already supports JavaEE 6. As I didn't find anything about it in google, I thought that it didn't, until I found a comment saying that Oracle WebLogic Server 11g is Java EE 6 complaint.

Despite that, I haven't found yet the modules to support the new Java EE 6 features.

Does somebody knows something about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it doesn't, WebLogic 11g is a Java EE 5 application server (you can check the datasheet for the standard and the enterprise edition [here](http://www.oracle.com/appserver/docs/weblogic-server-se-datasheet.pdf) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/appserver/docs/weblogic-server-ee-datasheet.pdf)).

AFAIK, Java EE 6 support is planned for WebLogic 12g (to be released in 2011).

Comment: Are you sure that WL11g is a JEE5 only server? I just installed it and it comes package with Sun's JDK 1.6 & jRockit 1.6

Comment: @bakoyaro -- JDK version number and Java EE version number are not synonymous. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013958/correlation-between-jee-j2ee-to-j2se-jdk-versions

Answer (score 12):

WebLogic 11g is fully Java EE 5 compliant [1], but WebLogic 11gR1 PS3 (10.3.4) included *some* Java EE 6 technologies [2,3]. The next major release will be fully Java EE 6 compliant [4].

@bakoyaro - WebLogic 10.3 supports JDK 6, but only Java EE 5 [5].

[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-javaee5-jsp-141098.html

[2] http://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_1034_released

[3] http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/weblogic_developer_production_web_profile

[4] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/learnmore/weblogic-javaee6-webcasts-358613.html

[5] http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/notes/new.html#wp1093291

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic 12c implements Java EE 6, and is backwards compatible for previous versions of Java EE.