# WebLogic Server :: The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, specifications, weblogic11g

When I try running an application using the WebLogic 11g 10.3.5 server, it shows that "The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification."

How to overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: What part is causing you problems? There might be a library that can fill the void.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166283/weblogic-11g-and-javaee-6

Answer (score 6):

Develop your application using the supported version of the specification (Servlet 2.5), or use another application server supporting the version 3.0, or wait for the version of WebLogic that supports version 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic 11 does not support Servlet 3.0

You need to move on to Weblogic 12. According to the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#CJAIIAGA), Servlet 3.0 is now supported.