# Application does not start with Spring Boot 1.2.1 + Spring Security + Servlet 2.5

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, servlet-2.5

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security starter that works well in "modern" (i.e. Servlet 3.0+) J2E servers such as Tomcat 7 or Jetty 8.

My problem is that I have to run the application in a Weblogic 10.3 server (the Production one), that implements Servlet 2.5 specification and does not support Servlet 3.0+, according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17230224/2120773) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685836/weblogic-server-the-server-does-not-support-version-3-0-of-the-j2ee-web-modul).

I've seen that an effort is made aside the official Spring Boot project to support legacy server / apps, a.k.a. the [Spring Boot Legacy project](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy) that works well... until I activate the spring-boot-starter-security dependency :-S

And effectively, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy/issues/3) on the Spring Boot Legacy tracker.

I reproduce exactly the same error on a Tomcat 6 (Servlet 2.5) server (see below).

**So, does anyone already succeeded in making Spring Boot + Spring Security + Servlet 2.5 based server work together ?**

```
2015-02-03 23:17:12.208 ERROR 2662 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChainRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'securityFilterChainRegistration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/DispatcherType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'securityFilterChainRegistration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/DispatcherType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 58 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/DispatcherType
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.securityFilterChainRegistration(SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$300a37f.CGLIB$securityFilterChainRegistration$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$300a37f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6b869afe.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$300a37f.securityFilterChainRegistration(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 59 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.DispatcherType
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659984/how-to-use-websphere-runtime-libraries-inside-spring-boot-as-stand-along-app/37243414#37243414) Disabling the JMX helps to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a viable solution. I post it, if it can help someone else.

The problem effectively came from Spring Security. I found [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi) from the Spring Security reference documentation that help me a bit.

Finally, the things I do to make my application running on a Tomcat 6 (Servlet 2.5) or Tomcat 7 (Servlet 3.0) were :

- in pom.xml (again), keep the dependency to spring-boot-legacy
- in pom.xml, replace the dependency to spring-boot-starter-security by the ones of Spring Security (spring-security-web and spring-security-config)
- add the @EnableWebMvcSecurity annotation on my security configuration class
- in web.xml, add the filter springSecurityFilterChain with filter class org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

These are my dependencies in pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

This is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.acme.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And this is my Spring Security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

        @Inject
        protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }
}
```

Comment: This solution works well on Tomcat 6 but not on WebLogic 10.3.X :-/

I've found [a blog post](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse/issues/15) that proposes to use the Spring Boot application property "spring.main.sources" as :

    spring.main.sources=com.acme.Application

To be tested...

Comment: were you able to deploy the app in WLS 10.3.6? I'm in the same boat, forced to deal with WLS 10.3.6 :(

Comment: I'm sorry but "no", we were not able to deploy on WLS 10.3.6... After a full week of lots of problems (web.xml, weblogic.xml, class loading order / dependencies) we had to give up and to convince the client to move on a more modern server. He finally accept to move on Tomcat 7 (yet it is an old insurance domain leader !). Sorry and good luck !

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me :(  `javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception`