# How to use WebSphere Runtime libraries inside Spring Boot as stand along app

Tags: spring-boot, ejb, websphere

I am trying to build a Spring Boot console app.
to get started I am using the spring initializer v 1.3.1

it's simple 'hello world' with no Web, no JPA, no anything
Now I edited the pom.xml and added a dependency to jar file called 
'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar '

all of a sudden I get the following errors upon build

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.management.MBeanServer]: Factory method 'mbeanServer' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.MBeanServerNotFoundException: Could not access WebSphere's AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory/getMBeanServer method; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

How can I include Websphere 8 run time libraries into Spring-Boot stand-alone app

Goal:
I am trying to develop a simple stand alone java app, that will invoke EJB services via IIOP. This app runs out-side (as a stand alone client) and talks to EJB app inside websphere.

Comment: I am still looking for answers, but I found a temp workaround, and that is i downgraded the Spring boot version to 1.1.1 from 1.3.1

Answer (score 2):

By default, jmx is enabled in spring-boot.

If you are not using JMX for your project. Add this line in the application.properties. That should solve this problem.

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to my `application.properties` for Spring boot `1.3.5.RELEASE`

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.jta.enabled=false
```