# Schedule a Java program to run everyday in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic11g

I want to schedule a java program in weblogic that runs every night 
can you any one help on this ?

Ee can do this using thread but I don`t think that is efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

[WebLogic 11g is a Java EE 5 compliant application server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169173/1907906). So you can  use the [`TimerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html):

```
@Singleton
public class TimerSessionBean {
  @Resource
  TimerService timerService;

  @Schedule(minute="0", hour="1")
  public void atOneInTheNight() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: this will run every night at 1:00 clock?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Take a look at the `@Schedule` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Quartz Scheduler. http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: but what if i want do it my own?

Comment: @123456789 Why don't you want to use a standard? Java EE includes what you need. In addition, there are libraries like Quartz you can use.

Comment: @123456789 why do you want to reinvent the wheel again. Use quartz scheduler.