# How to find the version of JPA?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee

How to understand What JPA version I'm using in EJB?
Is JPA built-in EJB?

Regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With a Java EE 5 container, you get JPA 1.0 (specified in the [JSR 220 - Enterprise JavaBeans, Version 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220)).

With a Java EE 6 container, you get JPA 2.0 (specified in the [JSR 317: Java Persistence 2.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) which is now dedicated).

And if you are providing your own JPA implementation, well, it depends on the implementation and the version you provide :)

Here are some JPA 2.0 implementations and their respective versions:

- EclipseLink 2.0+
- Hibernate EntityManager 3.5+
- OpenJPA 2.0+
- DataNucleus 2.1.0+

Comment: How can I find this standalone specification in JEE6?

Comment: @Navid I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but I added some links to the specs.

Comment: Are Persistence Providers implementing JPA? if yes, so I can not use just JPA because it is just API, isn't it? and I have to use one of JPA 2.0 implementations ?

Comment: @Navid: Yes, persistence providers are providing JPA implementations. And yes, JPA is indeed just an API (like the whole Java EE platform) and you have to use an implementation.

Comment: Tahnks for you answer, but would you please tell me the version of JDK in difference with JEE? or there is a relation between them?

Comment: @Navid: Sure, see [Correlation between JEE / J2EE to J2SE / JDK versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013958/correlation-between-jee-j2ee-to-j2se-jdk-versions/2015780#2015780).

Answer (score 0):

No JPA and EJBs are not related at all, they are totally independent. JPA is not built in EJBs. The javaee-api 6 which is the JAVA EE 6 container gives you the code for EJB 3 and JPA 2.+. In order to implement EJB3 you can use weblogic or JBoss or any application container. To implement JPA you can use hibernate, OpenJPA etc.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```