# java program developed - which Development Kits do other people need to use the project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java

I've developed a java web application. I've installed the Java EE SDK 5 and Java SDK 6u23.

When another person wants to use this project - I mean for example in Netbeans or Eclipse - so that the person can change the code and compile the project and use it then, does the person need the same Java EE SDK and Java SDK?
The same = Java SDK 6u23? Or does another Java SDK version also work? Are they downwards or upwards compatible?

I would like to know it so that I can say the person "Hey, you need at least Java EE SDK 5 and Java SDK 6u23 to get it working (or a newer version)"

Comment: Why did you use Java EE 5 (which builds on Java 5) with Java 6?

Comment: I dont know, I started a year ago and just downloaded it like this. I researched too but I found out that this is no problem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013958/correlation-between-jee-j2ee-to-j2se-jdk-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will all depend on the code you wrote. Some features might not be available in older jdk releases. If the other person tries to compile and run in an older jdk you'll know for sure. You're better off that each person working on a project uses the same setup though.

Comment: Ok. So if I say the person should install java ee sdk 5 and java sdk 6u23 (or newer versions), it should work, right? (6u22 can but must not work, correct?)

Comment: Just keep the rule in mind that each person on the same project has to use the same jdk for developing. And I agree with Matt that you should look into which jdk you are really using. It's pointless (impossible? / dangerous?) to have them both in the same project. Chances are you're only using the Java 6 SDK and should therefor keep the JEE 5 one in the fridge until you really need it.

Comment: Well, in my project I can find the following: Project Properties: Libraries: Java Platform: JDK 1.6 AND Project Properties: Run: Server: Apache Tomcat 6.0.26 and Java EE Version: Java EE 5. I mean, this obviously works and it seems that I am using both JDKs?

Comment: You obviously have them both downloaded and 'installed' and you are referencing them both somehow in the same project. Is this within an Eclipse environment? The question remains though: are you using JEE specific libraries in your project or not? If I'm not mistaken it's not needed to run Tomcat.

Comment: It is in Netbeans. I use a lot of JEE API packages, like javax.servlet., javax.mail and so on...

Comment: Then my assumption was wrong. I'm not used to working in NetBeans but I find it strange that the Libraries part of your project properties wouldn't list JEE5 if you are indeed using packages from JEE ..