# Difference between JDK, J2EE and J2SE codename

Tags: jakarta-ee, java

I have seen the same topics here and some topics on other sites, but I'm really still confused, how does Sun name those versions.

Here is my knowledge about those codenames. Please check it and correct for me:

**JDK:** stands for **Java Development Kit** can be known as the most basic of Java, used to develop client side application (such as desktop application (use Swing, awt, ...) or Applet,...)

**J2EE:** stands for **Java Enterprise Edition** used to develop application on Server side (such as Servlet, EJB,...)

**J2SE:** I have no idea about this yet !!!

When I have read on some famous forum/site (`stackoverflow`, `byte`, `javabranch` etc...). there are some different answers for my question. (or maybe I understand wrong because my bad English).

Here some answer that I have search:

JDK is like J2SEE !!! Oh, I don't trust this so much. when I config Glassfish server on Eclipse, Eclipse warns that this version need j2se 1.4 later (but I have JDK 7 or jdk 1.7 !!!)

[correlation-between-jee-j2ee-to-j2se-jdk-versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013958/correlation-between-jee-j2ee-to-j2se-jdk-versions) I don't under stand phrase `will be built`(the post that have marked correct answer).

For example:

> J2EE 1.4 is the Enterprise Edition of version 1.4 of the Java
>   platform, and thus will be built on J2SE 1.4.

So, it means J2EE is the "beta version" of J2SE ??!! Please explain for me.

I tried to learn EJB, so which version I need to install ?

Thanks :)

Comment: This can be easily googled or searched on wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry. it's so confusing ! if it's so easy to know, why so many posts say about these confusing name. and many answers are so different

Comment: Please read up to date resources. "J2SE" and "J2EE" have been renamed to "Java SE" and "Java EE" since ages.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @BalusC, but for example I'm attending a University course right now, and they still used J2SE in their description. :|  
> - Android Development Environment  
> - J2SE Desktop Development Environment  
> - Operating systems, services of modern operating systems  
> - Application Framework (J2SE vs. Android)  
> - Files  
> - Lifecycle Methods (J2SE vs. Android)  
> - Multithreaded applications (J2SE & Android)  
> - Concepts in multithreading  
> - Network programming

Answer (score 11, accepted):

J2SE is a old name. Now his name is Java SE.

Java SE is the base of java. With Java SE you can build java applications, like Swing, Applets, etc.

Java EE is a specification for enterprise applications. When you need to develop one application and run it under a JBoss, Glassfish, Websphere and other container, you are talking about Java EE.

You should read this article about java ee: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition

Comment: Oh. I have search about download JSE and JDK on Oracle page. if (JSE == JDK), why in Oracle page, there are two different pages for download JDK and JSE ! Please make it clear for me.

Comment: Do not use the abbreviations "JSE" and "JEE". They are wrong. Use "Java SE" and "Java EE". Also the statement JSE == JDK is wrong.

Comment: JSE comes in two different packages: JRE (runtime - trimmed down edition that is enough to run JSE applications), JDK (devkit - full edition that is needed to develop and run JSE applications). 
JEE is a different thing and is only a specification (API).

Comment: Because the JDK can come packaged with other tools, like application servers, IDEs, etc. The other only contains the Java Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 2):

Java SE is the generic name which has two different components in it. JDK and the JRE. Java EE as explained above is the enterprise edition which has more components in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may think in development when say JDK, and thnk in usability when say JRE.

J2SE and J2EE are APIs for base java application and web enterpise java applications respectively