# Java EE vs Java SE: version mismatch?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've been wondering if there is a correlation between versions of Java EE working on top of Java SE. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013958/correlation-between-java-ee-j2ee-to-j2se-jdk-versions), but the answers there are outdated and not satisfying. My question is:

- is there a tight coupling between EE and SE versions so that java EE 8 will only work with Java 1.8, java ee 7 will work only with java 1.7 and so on?
- if above is false (i.e. you can mix versions), is above the preferred way? Does it make sense to run java EE 6 on java SE 1.8 (just an example)?

I know that Java EE is just a bag of specifications, but do these specifications enforce java SE version anyhow?

Comment: yes it does. Using two different versions, where a lot of functionality is common, wouldn't make sense. I am open to surprises, but AFAIK it does use SE underneath. A proof is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html). It doesn't spill too much of the guts, but it should be enough to satisfy you. Also if [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115769/what-are-these-different-java-versions-for) helps you in anyway.

Comment: Best suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hagubear I knew all this (the links you gave). Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather about which SE versions EE server can work with. Like here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/Java_Environments_Supported_By_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_61.html

Comment: so there's no tight correlation, but there might be a hard dependency for a chosen application server, right? E.g. Glassfish for EE7 works for SE 6 and SE 7 (just put some fake versions) - does it work like that?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz it looks like it. Also take a look at this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_se_8_and_java) : " From a Java EE point of view, the Java EE 7 specification requires at least Java SE 7. So clearly, nothing prevents you from using Java SE 8 with Java EE 7. A lot of us are in fact using early builds of Java SE 8 with GlassFish on a daily basis without any problem!"

Answer (score 1):

As per oracle document [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html)

> **Java EE**
>
> The Java EE platform is built on top of the Java SE platform. The Java
> EE platform provides an API and runtime environment for developing and
> running large-scale, multi-tiered, scalable, reliable, and secure
> network applications.

So ideally Java SE must be higher or equivalent version when compared to JAVA EE. According to this statement its possible to run java EE 6 on java SE 1.8 and not the other-way round.