# Can anyone tell me what a "Java EE stack" means in simpler terms

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

What does the term " Java EE stack " means in simpler terms with an example

Comment: Doesn't the wiki texts of the tags tell it all?

Comment: No. I did not get any direct answer. I need a meaning of the term and what ever tags are explanations of latest Java ee stacks.                                 Could anyone help me rather than making my question not useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106820/what-is-java-ee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means Java EE technology stack, ie. all the JSRs that are part of a java EE release and whose implementation will be provided by all Java EE certified application servers. (you won't need to provide yourself the libraries in your application).
 Here for example is the Java EE 6 stack:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html