# How to set servlet for java 11

Tags: java, servlets

I have installed development environment `Intellij ideea` and `java 11`. I read that `java 11` do not support `javax.servlet package`, because it is a part of `Java EE` and can not create a `servlet`. But what do I need to do to create a servlet? To install java 8 EE? or if there is a video how to fix it, because I've read a lot of articles but I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774924/just-what-is-java-ee-really, Java and JavaEE are two different but complementary things. Actually it's Jakarta EE now by the way.

Comment: Jakarta EE (formerly Java EE) is merely a wide collection of a few dozen specifications for software that you might want to run on your Java SE implementation (a JDK). [Jakarta Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) is one such spec. The Servlet spec defines an API which is represented as Java code in a JAR, mostly interfaces. You need a copy of that JAR while developing. But do not bundle with your Servlet. You will deploy your Servlet to a Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty. That container comes with its own copy of the API along with its own particular implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally do it with Java 11, the only depedency you need is:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Here you can find a working demo example https://github.com/asgarov1/servlet_app

Comment: Shouldn’t you add the element `<scope>provided</scope>`?

Comment: Answer could be improved by showing both the old `javax.*` and new `jakarta*` package naming.