# Why there is number two in J2EE name?

Tags: jakarta-ee, definition

As dicussed about the name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106820/what-is-java-ee), I wonder why we have the number two 2 in the name J2EE? Was there J1EE or J0EE?

Comment: @Joe Not duplicated at all. I focus on the number two in the name while your mentioned one is about what it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Java Ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/386242/java/java/difference-JEE-ee#1687650)

> Sun went through a name change a little bit ago. The first release of
>   Java was called simply Java.
>   Then the platform was updated and was
>   called Java 2 and we got versions like: Java 2 version 1.3, 1.4... And
>   you got the Standard Edition names looking like: J2SE 1.3, 1.4, ...
>
> The Enterprise Edition followed the same scheme: Java 2 Enterprise
>   Edition version 1.2, 1.3... Which came out to be J2EE 1.3, ...
>
> Because it was confusing people why Java 2 had versions 1.x for so
>   long they renamed it in later versions to be: Java Standard Edition
>   5.0, 6.0, 7.0 or just Java 5 and Java 6 instead of J2SE 1.5 and J2SE 1.6.
>
> The Enterprise Edition followed suit with JEE 5 instead of J2EE 1.5.
>
> The difference, then is that Java Enterprise Editions < version 5 have
>   names like J2EE 1.3 or J2EE 1.4 while Java Enterprise Editions >= 5
>   will have names like JEE 5, JEE 6, ...

Comment: Awesome explancation and so much clearer for me now! Thank you @Salih Erikci