# What is the difference between JEE and J2EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to learn about the difference between JEE and J2EE. I guess both are Java Enterprise development tools or environments. But what makes them exactly different and similar?

Comment: Care to [read the java-ee tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-ee/info)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The acronym *JEE* is a actually a misnomer and its use should be discouraged. Quoting from the [Java EE Platform Specification page](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/JEE):

> ### There is nothing named JEE! Never use that name!
>
> **The correct short name is "Java EE"**
>
> When the enterprise Java platform was first introduced, it was called
>   "Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition", with the abbreviation "J2EE".
>   [When we revised the naming of the Java platform](http://java.com/en/about/javanaming.jsp), we [didn't just drop
>   the "2"](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=35561).
>
> One of the big reasons we changed the names of the platforms is
>   because we wanted to emphasize that they're all "Java". The old names
>   of "J2EE, "J2SE", and "J2ME" don't do that. Java is what's important
>   to us. Java is why we're here. Java is the value we share. We need to
>   make that clear to the world by talking about "Java EE".
>
> Please, use only the correct name "Java EE". If that's too much to say
>   or type, call it "EE". (No, not "double-E".)

---

Related questions:

- [What is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106820/1426227)
- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7295096/1426227)
- [A summary of all Java EE specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082364/1426227)

Related content outside Stack Overflow:

- [Java EE at a Glance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html)
- [Java EE 7 Specification APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/)
- [Java EE on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition)
- [Java EE 7 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/index.html)

Comment: Thank you Cassio. I am really sorry for the typing mistakes I did, I was in hurry to know about the two terms,java EE and J2EE. I found exactly what you mentioned in one website and something different in  another website. Now it is clear for me and is good lesson, as I lost 6 of my reputations to learn it!!!..Thank you.