# How to correctly render jsf tags?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2, jboss

I'm newer in javaEE development and I have an issue to display jsf tags. Once I lunch the JBoss server (JBoss 10.2.0) I have this following error and an empty page

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

This is the content of the web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
```

This is the content of pom.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>sn.ucad.masterbi</groupId>
<artifactId>GestionOuvrier</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This is the content of login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Authentification</title>
    </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
          <p:messages id="messages" />
          <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel for="nameUser" value="Name User:" />
                <p:inputText id="nameUser" value="#{loginManagedBean.user.login}" />

                <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                <p:password id="password" value="#{loginManagedBean.user.password}" />

                <p:commandButton value="Valider" icon="ui-icon-star" action="#{loginManagedBean.connexion}" ajax="false">
                </p:commandButton>

          </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have in your external libraries:

```
Maven: org.primefaces:primefaces:6.0
```

which contains: primefaces jar with the desired taglib.xml.
If not then you should reimport your dependencies from maven nexus.

Also do not use J2EE name for Java EE([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702229/what-is-the-difference-between-jee-and-j2ee)).

By using JBoss you probably do not need all of these libs for servlet, jsf etc. Because JBoss is application server not just container therefore you already have all these libs included.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I verified the PrimeFaces library. I see the jar file but I dont see the taglib.xml. 
Also I forgot to mention that when I write only HTML or text it appears.

Comment: I tried your .XHTML and it works fine. (I need to add </h:body>
</html> to the end) The problem has to be the absence of taglib in your primefaces-6.0.jar try to change version to 6.1 taglib should be located in META-INF folder.