# JAX-RS: Custom class object no injected into a ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

I've created an `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation like this:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
@Secured
@Dependent
public class BearerFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{

    @Inject protected MemcachedApplicationResources memcachedResources;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        //this.memcachedResources is null here.
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to inject a `MemcachedApplicationResources` object into `memcachedResources` field.

`MemcachedApplicationResources` is like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MemcachedApplicationResources {}
```

Why is it `null`?

**EDIT**

I've just created a `beans.xml` file with this content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

However, it's still `null`.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I've also tried to create an `Filter` instead of a `ContainerRequestFilter`:

```
@WebFilter(
    dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST },
    urlPatterns = { "/cmng/*" },
    initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "excludedPaths", value = "log") }
    )
public class BearerWebFilter implements Filter
{

    @Inject protected MemcachedResources memcachedResources;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        //here, this.memcachedResources is a injected proxy!
    }
}
```

Why using a `Filter` class the field is injected?

Comment: What's your `beans.xml` like?

Comment: I don't have any `beans.xml` file.

Comment: If you don't use CDI 1.2, a `beans.xml` is mandatory. Otherwise injection won't work.

Comment: I'm using a JAX-RS agnostic implementation. Currently, I'm deploying my web applications on a Wildfly 10.1.0.Final that has the latest RestEasy implementaiton.

Comment: For your web application, create an empty `beans.xml` file under the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Sorry, it keeps `null`

Comment: I've added a picture on post.

Comment: Can I test with some else?

Comment: Can you get the instance using `CDI.current().select(MemcachedApplicationResources.class).get()`?

Comment: Yes! It returns an MemcachedResources$Proxy-like class object

Comment: How do you wire in this filter?  Do you have an implementation of JAX-RS's `Application`?  By any chance are you including your JAX-RS implementation in the WAR file, or are you just uing RestEasy?

Answer (score 1):

The injection should work if:

- You have a `beans.xml` file under `WEB-INF` (not mandatory for CDI 1.2).
- Your filter is a bean managed by CDI.

Depending on your container, you may require an extra dependency to make CDI works with RESTEasy, but it should work out-of-the-box with WildFly. See the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#CDI) for more details.

---

If it doesn't work, you still can try to get the instance programmaticaly using:

```java
MemcachedApplicationResources bean = 
    CDI.current().select(MemcachedApplicationResources.class).ge‌​t();
```

Comment: I've edited the post again. Basicly, I've created a `Filter` class instead of a `ContainerRequestFilter`. Now it works. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jordi _Now it works. Any ideas?_ CDI injection works out-of-the-box in servlets (and servlet filters).

Comment: But, why doesn't it works using JAXRS `ContainerRequestFilter`? The project is the same...